# Access token issue while accessing the graph API

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the code below to fetch user from the azure AD using the graph API, but somehow I am getting the token access issue while doing so.

```
static async void MakeRequest()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            /* OAuth2 is required to access this API. For more information visit:
               https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/common-app-authentication-tasks */



            // Specify values for the following required parameters
            queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
            // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
            // var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/microsoft.onmicrosoft.com/users/{v-sidmis@microsoft.com}?" + queryString;

            var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/users?api-version=1.6";

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            }


        }
```

This code is taken up from TechNet.

Comment: Your code is missing the part where it should send the access--token as a header for the `client` object

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Can you please provide a sample code for that?

Comment: This is the article that I have used.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-rest-sample/blob/master/Microsoft%20Graph%20REST%20ASPNET%20Connect/Microsoft%20Graph%20REST%20ASPNET%20Connect/Helpers/SampleAuthProvider.cs

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I'll go through this.

Comment: Hi Haitham, 
I went through the link but unfortunately I'm not getting the logic. can you please help me with the authentication part in my code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to acquire the token. There are lots of scenario to integrate the application with Azure AD. You can refer it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios).

For example, if you want to use the Azure AD Graph in a daemon or service application, we can use the **Client Credential flow**.

1 . First we need to register an web application on the [portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/)( detail steps refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-integrating-applications)) and grant the permission to read the directory data like figure below:
[image]

2 . And then we can get the **clientId**, **secret**, **tenantId** from the portal and use the code below to acquire token(need to install the [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/))

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";
string clientId = "";
string secret = "";
string resrouce = "https://graph.windows.net";

var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, credential).Result.AccessToken;

Console.WriteLine(token);
```

3 . Then we can use this token to call the Azure AD Graph REST directly or we can use the [graph client library for Azure AD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) to retrieve the users. Here is the code samples for your reference:

```
//use the Azure AD client library
string accessToken = "";
string tenantId = ""; 
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);

ActiveDirectoryClient client = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, async () => await Task.FromResult(accessToken));

foreach(var user in client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage)
            Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);

//using the HTTP request 
var client = new HttpClient();
var tenantId = "";
var uri = $"https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users?api-version=1.6";
var token = "";
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

### Update

The secrecy is available for the web application/web API when you create an application. Then you can generate the key by keys section like figure below. After you save the app, you can copy the secrect now.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information..really helpful!! i registered my app in the ad and obtained all the endpoints and id's but I am unable to locate the secret.

Comment: The secrecy is available for the web application/web API when you create an application. Then you can generate the key by **keys** section. Please refer the post for the figure.

Comment: @dotnetman Have you fixed this issue now? If you still have the issue, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Xue: yes the issue is resolved. Thanks for the help!